# plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex from CPTScatterPlot Delegate

Tags: ios

how to connect the plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex from CPTScatterPlot Delegate method. when i am clicking on indexes of scatter plot it is not rendering to the method. why? could you help me please.thanks

Comment: how to add the delegate method?

Comment: i have used CPTScatterPlotDelegate *delegateObj=[CPTScatterPlotDelegate alloc]init];      and delegateObj.delegate=self; and delegateObj.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection=10.0f; but not working

Comment: i have added these code in view didLoad method

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you adopt the protocol first. So, in your `.h` file declare as follows :

```
#import "CorePlot-CocoaTouch.h"
// CPTPlotSpaceDelegate is optional, used for other things, and of course CPTPlotDataSource is mandatory, and for your purpose, CPTScatterPlotDelegate is also mandatory
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <CPTPlotSpaceDelegate, CPTPlotDataSource, CPTScatterPlotDelegate> { 

}
```

And in your `.m` file :

```
self.linePlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
self.linePlot.delegate = self;

-(void)scatterPlot:(CPTScatterPlot *)plot plotSymbolWasSelectedAtRecordIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    // Your logic here
}
```